# Terraform github_repository 401 in module but works in main scope

Tags: github, terraform, hcl, personal-access-token

I have a github provider declared with a personal access token.
Trying to create a repository like the following works:

```
resource "github_repository" "test" {
  name = "test"
  visibility = "private"
}
```

However, I want to create something reusable. Whenever I try to create that exact same `github_repository` from a submodule, I get the following error:

```
╷
│ Error: POST https://api.github.com/user/repos: 401 Requires authentication []
│
│   with module.test.module.repository.github_repository.test,
│   on modules\serverless_api_repository\main.tf line 1, in resource "github_repository" "source_code":
│    1: resource "github_repository" "test" {
│
╵
```

Why can't I create a `github_repository` from a submodule, when it works in the main scope?

Comment: Is the provider configured the same for both modules?

Comment: There is no provider explicitly configured for the submodule. I understand that the submodule will use the same provider configurations defined in the main scope.

Comment: Because the provider isn't specified in the submodule I don't think it will have access to the environment variables as it would in the root module. I would specify the required provider in the module but never set a max version (min version only if required).

Comment: @JakeNelson According to [the docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/module-providers#default-behavior-inherit-default-providers) it seems like I shouldn't need to specify a provider in the submodule. The submodule should just inherit the github provider from the parent scope because there is no `alias` and I don't specify any `providers` argument in the `module` block.

Comment: @JSONBrody, can you please show us how you are configuring your providers and credentials being used by this provider?

Comment: @JakeNelson it's just a `github` provider with only a PAT for `token`, no other args. Version is `~> 4.18.0`.

Comment: The token is is defined in the provider config static for testing, passed in as a Terraform var, or specified as an OS environment variable?

Comment: @JakeNelson hardcoded into the provider declaration

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Or if you found another solution, please add it here, I'd love to learn how you solved it!

Comment: @JakeNelson I did not solve it. I abandoned the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Did a [quick check](https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+child+module) to see if anyone else is facing this issue and found [this](https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/issues/846). The resources are different to yours I think but it may be the same issue regardless.

You could try passing the provider down to the module call.

e.g.

```
provider "github" {
  ...
}

module "my-repo" {
  source    = "./my-repo"
  providers = {
    github  = "github"
  }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to add the Organization parameter at the Github Provider level:

```
provider "github" {
  organization = "myorgname"
  token        = var.token
}
```

That did the work.